# NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "test":String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a simple create action where I'm passing some params, but getting an error of undefined method permit for:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "twest":String):

following is the params that I'm getting in the request:

```
{"email"=>"admin@mailinator.com", "promo_code"=>"test", "description"=>"this is test", "action"=>"create"}
```

and the promo_code_params

```
def promo_code_params
  params.require(:promo_code).permit(:email,:code, :description)
end
```

the create action

```
def create
 @promo_code = @reward.promo_codes.new(promo_code_params)
 # code
 # code
end
```

Comment: Please, post your view code? As well as `new` action in controller

Answer (score 0):

Your params hash is not on the expected way your `promo_code_params` defines. It should look like:

```
{ "promo_code" => {"email"=>"admin@mailinator.com", "code"=>"test", "description"=>"this is test"}, "action"=>"create"}
```

or you promo_code_params should be like:

```
def promo_code_params
  params.permit(:email,:promo_code,:description)
end
```

Hope that helps you understand what's wrong.

Comment: This helped a lot